# Excel Formula finding x and y percentage

Tags: excel, math, percentage

I am struggling to figure out how to get a formula to figure out how many and what percentage of tickets we sold for a show. 
We sold tickets at $20 and $30. 764 tickets were sold for a total of $19,740. How do i write a formula to find the percentage a number of tickets sold at $20 and the percentage and number sold at $30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let x->the number of 20$ tickets
and y->the number of 30$ tickets
then: 
x + y = 764 
or
x = 764 - y

we know x*20 + y*30 = 19740
substituting (764 - y) for x
(764 - y)*20 + y*30 = 19740
evaluating you get y= 446
now that we know y.
x = 764 - y = 318
percentage sold at 30$:
(446/764)*100 = 58.38%
percentage sold at 20$:
(318/764)*100 = 41.62
```